# Disabling partial variable names in subsetting data frames

Tags: r

I have just discovered that R will allow me to use partial variable names to subset data frames, as long as they are uniquely defined. I find this dangerous and am wondering if there is a way (like an environment variable or something) to disable this behavior.

Here is what I mean:

```
myframe <- data.frame(othervar=1:3, myvar=4:6)
print(myframe$myv)

[1] 4 5 6
```

What I would like to happen is the same as for

```
print(myframe$wrong)

NULL
```

Any way to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. You can use `options(warnPartialMatchDollar=TRUE)` to get a warning when you do this (I'm using r-devel ... I *think* this is in the released version??), and you could use `options(warn=2)` to upgrade warnings to errors (but this would upgrade *all* warnings to errors ...)

I believe the standard advice/best practice is to use `[[`-indexing instead

```
myframe <- data.frame(othervar=1:3, myvar=4:6)
myframe$myv
## [1] 4 5 6   (no problem)
myframe$wrong
## NULL

options(warnPartialMatchDollar=TRUE)
myframe$myv
## [1] 4 5 6
## Warning message:
## In `$.data.frame`(myframe, myv) :
##   Partial match of 'myv' to 'myvar' in data frame
options(warn=2) ## upgrade warnings to errors
myframe$myv
## Error in `$.data.frame`(myframe, myv) : 
##   (converted from warning) Partial match of 'myv' to 'myvar' in data frame

myframe[["myv"]]
## NULL
```

Comment: Aye, Ben. Said option has been around for a few years.

Comment: OK, great. Warnings would actually be sufficient. Zheyuan, can you just give me a code snippet to change the global option?

Comment: Never mind. I got it. I put `options(warnPartialMatchDollar=TRUE)` into .Rprofile.