# Code running when column doesn't exist (albeit with a number on the end)? - Confused

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe `(df)` (note that I call the column `'Description2'` with a number on the end):

```
ID = c(1,2)
Description2 = c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lacinia")
df = data.frame(ID, Description2)
```

If I use the following code, where I refer to the column `'Description'` which DOES NOT EXIST as it omits a number on the end, it still runs but creates a new column with the data from `'Description2'`:

```
df$Description = str_replace_all(df$Description, "[^[:graph:]]", " ")
```

If I refer to a column which is spelt different i.e. with a letter changed, it of course doesn't run and errors e.g.

```
df$Descriptions = str_replace_all(df$Descriptions, "[^[:graph:]]", " ")
```

Why is this happening?

Many thanks

Comment: It is a "feature", R likes partial matching, as long as it is a unique match on names. Try `df$Des` or even `df$D`

Comment: Oh I see. Interesting. I did not know that. Is there any way of disabling it?

Comment: I think you can't, see related, possible duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39843123/680068

Comment: Great, thank you for the link. What a pain that is.... I will have to use a workaround. Thank you!

Comment: the usual workaround would be to change `df$Description` to `df[["Description"]]`

Comment: I never rely on name partial matching, always use full names. What is your real use-case where you might end up with partial names?

Comment: I am designing a tool which cleans a large corpus for some users at work. The 'Description' column is entered by the user in a CSV, and I don't want it to create a new column if they slightly mistype it, I want it to error out. I just noticed Miffs workaround, which seems to do the job :)